# SqlClient freeing resources is slow (but not every time)

Tags: c#, resources, sqlclient

I have this problem for a very long time, but we are about to release, and it must be fixed.

I have an application, and in that application, I can call another (it can be the same application, but with different parameters).

A choice we made is to disable the caller until the called is up.

When I close the called, in some cases, there is a time for freeing ressources whitch lasts about 1500 ms, but not every time.

I used DotTrace to see what happen, and here is the stack :

[image: stack slow]

As we can see, the Finalize methode lasts 1500 ms, and I don't know why !!

For some programs, it only take a few ms.

So, if someone have an idee, ....

Thx, and Merry Christmas !

Comment: The garbage collector runs nondeterministically. That said I don't see why it should be causing you a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

I do not know why, but I solved the problem by adding a `GC.Collect ()` and `SqlConnection.ClearPool (_Connection);`